# Ui-router, ng-repeat and ui state

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I m developping an application in which I need to redirect the current user to a different state after a ressource creation.

Actually, I have a list of demands, and I need to show or create a quotation based on that demand.

Here's the view code :

```
<div class="landing-diags">
  <div class="current-projects">
    <div class="row project-summary" ng-repeat="demand in landingdiag.demandsList">
      <div class="col-md-2 project-block first-block {{project.projectType}}">
        <p class="project-strong">{{demand.user.firstname}} {{demand.user.lastname}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 project-block">
        <p class="project-strong">{{demand.creationDate | date:"dd/MM/yyyy"}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div ng-if="!demand.quotation">
          <button ng-click="landingdiag.createQuotation(demand)" class="btn btn-primary pull-right bar-btn">Create</button>
        </div>
        <div ng-if="demand.quotation">
          <button ui-sref="app.state.concerned({id: demand._id})" class="btn btn-primary pull-right bar-btn">Show</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here's the controller methods implied :

```
createQuotation (demand) {
    this.DemandsService.createQuotation(demand).$promise.then((response) => {
      this.redirectToQuote(demand);
    });
  }

redirectToQuote (demand) {
  this.$state.transitionTo('app.state.concerned', {id: demand._id});
}
```

**Problem**

My problem is that I m never redirected when creating a quotation. If I console log the redirectToQuote method, I pass inside of it. So it seems that my problem is on the $state.go call.

However, when I try to redirect directly using the redirectToQuote method inside of my view on the "show" button like following :

```
<div ng-if="demand.quotation">
  <button ng-click="landingdiag.redirectToQuote(demand)" class="btn btn-primary pull-right bar-btn">Accéder au devis</button>
</div>
```

I m well redirected to the concerned state

Comment: if you use `state.go` instead `state.transitionTo` it's the same?

Comment: Inside you promise then() function you are pointing to your promise object not to the controller with this.redirectToQuote(demand).

Answer (score 1):

I am concerned about the `this.redirectToQuote` within `createQuotation()`  which is called by `then()` as a callback. So the `this` object will definitely **not** be your controller.

Look at the first code snippet from todd: https://toddmotto.com/resolve-promises-in-angular-routes/
He is using bind.

You can also look at https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes from awesome Kyle Simpson
   or shorter from myself: http://blog.monkey-development.com/javascript/java/2015/12/18/javascript-this.html

Comment: Arrow functions with ES6 link the "this" context

Comment: can u create a plunker for your problem?